# Custom animation when switching tab/viewcontroller in UITabBarController

Tags: animation, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to make a UITabBarController tab switching animation similar to pop and push animation of navigation controller.

That's means if I select a tab at the left of the current tab, the view of new viewcontroller move into the screen from the left, and the view of old/current viewcontroller move out of screen to the right (similar to pop).

I can only achieve this at the moment but I don't know how to implement slide in/out effect.

Thank you!

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController:

    UIView *fromView = tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
    NSInteger fromIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    UIView * toView = [viewController view];
    NSInteger toIndex = [[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                        toView:toView
                      duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (finished) {
                            tabBarController.selectedIndex = toIndex;
                        }
                    }];
}
```